# How to apply XD design using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I do not know how to deal with pixel value and convert it to Dp Unit or percentage Unit.
And even the text, I do not know how to make it adaptive.
How can Jetpack Compose help me with these issues?
Thanks all

Comment: If the designer took into consideration layout/UI (minimum) widths and heights of your target devices (not the scaled pixel width/height or physical resolutions) then 1px = 1dp. For the percentage unit it depends which one you have in mind, but if you mean % of parent layout then you can use [`Modifier.weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#weight). I don't understand what you mean exactly with "adaptive text".

Comment: Pixel to dp conversion in Compose is done using a `.dp` extension function. Applicable for `Int`, `Float` and `Double`. Reference: `Dp.kt`.

Answer (score 0):

Scale factor of an iPhone 14 Pro Max cell is @3x I mean every point equal 3 pixels.

You've got a resolution of 1290 x 2796
and a points of design 430 x 932.

1290/3 430
2796/3 932

430x 932

Samsung A54 @3x scale factor
Samsung S23 @2x scale factor